# Is it possible to disable a dependency's feature when building with RLS?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following dependency configuration in `Cargo.toml`.

```
[dependencies.ffmpeg-sys]
version = "3.4.1"
default-features = false
features = ["avcodec", "avformat", "swresample", "static", "build"]
```

Adding the `build` feature hugely increases compile time and I only need to do it when building in release mode.

Is there a way to disable features of a dependency based on the build type (debug, release, RLS)?